# Android NativeCamera open with intent with camera flash off mode

Tags: android, flash, camera

I need to show Android native camera ( using intent ) with FlashMode Off.

I've read that intent parameters will not get guaranteed result because it depends on Phone Device implementation.

Can anybody please confirm that? I can't find official info about that

```
String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
//create parameters for Intent with filename
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");
//imageUri is the current activity attribute
        Uri imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
//create new Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.FLASH_MODE_OFF",1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you should do like :

1. Check whether flash light is
   available or not ?
2. If yes then Turn Off/On
3. If no then you can do whatever according to your app.
   needs

For **Checking availability of flash** in device:

You can use the following

```
 context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

which will return true if a flash is available, false if not.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html for more information.

**For turning on/off flashlight :**

I googled out and got this about android.permission.FLASHLIGHT. Android manifests' permission looks promising:

```
 <!-- Allows access to the flashlight -->
 <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
             android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
             android:protectionLevel="normal"
             android:label="@string/permlab_flashlight"
             android:description="@string/permdesc_flashlight" />
```

Then make use of [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and set [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html). The main parameter used here is [FLASH_MODE_TORCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_TORCH).

eg.

Code Snippet to turn on camera flash light.

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();     
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

Code snippet to turn off camera led light.

```
  cam.stopPreview();
  cam.release();
```

Comment: Thank You Himanshu for fast response but I think I need to open CameraPreview using intent. I'll update my question because I wasn't accurate.

Comment: you can check [this](http://androidexample.com/Camera_Photo_Capture_And_Show_Captured_Photo_On_Activity_/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=77&aaid=101) for opening camera and use above code to on or off flash

Comment: Himanshu Agarwal ,,can you please help me regarding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714771/android-camera-take-picture-failed-issue